# How can I cross-tabulate sparse matrices in R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, crosstab

The usual `table(x,y)` command fails when `x` and `y` are identically-dimensionalised sparse matrix objects as used in package `Matrix`. Now I could write a somewhat complicated cross-tabulation function which extracts row and column indicators and cell entry values and then compares these over the two matrices. But there should be an easier way. Does anybody know it?

Comment: If they are not to large you can cast them to `matrix` like: `table(as.matrix(x), as.matrix(y))`

Comment: I doubt if there's an easier way other than what @GKi suggested.

Comment: Well, thanks @GKi, but this is not a solution. I use sparse matrices because a regular matrix requires too much memory. This s what `R` tells me in response: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.0 Gb`

Comment: Could you please give a simplified example `x` and `y`, just to see what the expected output is?